# mongoose: accessing formData

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm building a geolocationAPI and i'm trying to query locations based on the min and max distance submitted by the user. However, i'm not being able to read those values in my controller.

My input:

```
<div class="form-group">                        
    <label>Min Distance</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="minDistance"><br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">                        
    <label>Max Distance</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="maxDistance"><br>
</div>
```

I tried this, to send it to the controller:

```
$scope.searchLocations = function () {
    $scope.formData.minDistance = $scope.minDistance;
    $scope.formData.maxDistance = $scope.maxDistance;
    $http.get('/api/places')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.searchLocations = data;
            //console.log($scope.formData.minDistance);
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
}
```

and on my controller i have this:

```
exports.find_all_locations_near = function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.minDistance > 0) 
  {
    Location.find({
      geolocation:
        { 
          $near :
          {
              $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ lat, lon ] },
              $minDistance: req.body.minDistance,
              $maxDistance: req.body.maxDistance
          }
        }
    }), function(err, location) {
      if (err) {
        //console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
      }
      else if (location =='')
        //res.json({ message: 'No location was found.' });
        res.json({ message: 'No location was found.' });
      else
      {
        res.json(location);
        res.json({ message: 'The end.' });
      }          
    };
  } else 
  {
    Location.find({}, function(err, location) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(location);
      //res.json(req.body);
    });
  }  
}
```

I assume i cant use req.body this way, right? How should i access the value of min and max distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GET request will not have a body.

To pass your search values, you can use query string parameters.

We can write a function to easily serialize a set of named values to form a query string to send to our backend.

```
function withQuery(url, parameters) {
    const query = Object.keys(parameters)
        .map(function (key) {
            return key + '=' + parameters[key];
        })
        .join('&');

    return query.length
        ? url + '?' + query
        : url;
}
```

We will leverage this function in the modified search method below

```
$scope.searchLocations = function () {        
    const url = withQuery('api/places', {
        minDistance: $scope.minDistance,
        maxDistance: $scope.maxDistance
    });

    $http.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.searchLocations = response.data;
            //console.log($scope.formData.minDistance);
        })
        .catch(function (reason) {
            console.log('Error: ' + reason);
        });
};
```

Note that we are using `then` and `catch` instead of `success` and `error` as the latter are deprecated and have problematic behavior.

In your server side code, you can access the values using the `query` property of the request

```
exports.find_all_locations_near = function(req, res) {
    const $minDistance = req.query.minDistance;
    const $maxDistance = req.query.maxDistance;

    if ($minDistance > 0) {
        Location.find({
            geolocation: { 
                $near: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [lat, lon]
                    },
                    $minDistance,
                    $maxDistance
                }
            }
        });
// ...
};
```

Query string parameters start with `?` and take the form `key=value`, delimited by `&`. They do not need to be declared as part of a route declaration and will be implicitly available on the `query` property of the `express.Request` value passed to the callback.

We can verify this behavior with the following snippet

```
app.use('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send(Object.entries(req.query)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key} ---> ${value}`)
    .join('<br>')
  );
});
```

and navigating to `/test?x=1&y=hello` in our browser which will render

> x ---> 1
>
> y ---> hello

**Note:** Although the `req.params` value is not populated with the query parameters, the `req.param` function can be called with a query parameter name to get its value. E.g. `const id = req.param('id')`. This makes the API feel inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks so much. Now, its apparently working. But now i`m getting this error:
GET http://localhost:3000/api/places?minDistance=10&maxDistance=20 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @SuperMonteiro sounds like your server is running on a different port (at least during development). You need to address your request to whichever port your express application is listening on. E.g: `'//localhost:5590/api/places'`. In an AngularJS app, you can set this globally in the config phase of your app by registering a request [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). Note this is an advanced technique.

Comment: no, i`m 100% confident thats the right port. theres something wrong with the query. when i switch back to the old one, i got no error.

app.route('/api/places')
    //.get(geolocation.find_all_locations_near);
    .get(geolocation.list_all_locations);  

with list all, which is just a list of all locations, i get no error. if i switch to find all, i get the error. Any idea?

Comment: That should be working. Query params don't need to be declared on the route. You could try using route parameters but query parameters really should suffice

Comment: @SuperMonteiro it seems that we have to use the `query` property and not the `params` property. I wrote a blank Express 4 app and it picks up the query string.

Comment: It still doesnt work. Connection refused again. Do i need to change my routes? https://github.com/supermonteiro/geolocationAPI

Comment: @SuperMonteiro I cloned your solution and fired up the server (stubbed or commented out all of the mongoose stuff since I don't have MongoDB installed). I hit the route immediately and all query string parameters were available on _**req.query**_. Sounds like your system is failing earlier.

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio 2017, use the debugger to find the problem, it is very good at debugging NodeJS applications if you have the NodeJS workload installed.

Comment: I will try that, I was mostly using sublime.

Comment: You can also use VS Code which is lightweight. You can just hit F5 and select node and it will auto configure itself for debugging. I suggested Visual Studio 2017 because I saw the .vs folder in your repo. Also, the problem you're having suggests that your application is failing to receive any requests, and likely has nothing to do with the specific route.

Comment: Its weird because the default query works. I'm new to nodejs and angular, and I'm having a hard time making this work. Do you have any idea what could be breaking it?

Comment: No sorry. My advice is to _never_ think about it as a NodeJS _and_ AngularJS project. Regardless of your directory structure, you have two discreet, separate applications. One is a single page application that runs in a browser and the other is a server API. You should learn each technology independently as they are completely orthogonal. Your backend could be written in Ruby or C# for all your browser app should care, and vice versa. The fact that they are both written in JavaScript is completely irrelevant as they run in different machines, in different memory spaces, communicating via JSON

Comment: So you believe my query is ok?

Answer (score 0):

To **Send value to server** change your route and $http method to post or it will leads your data expose to vulnerability.

Try to hide data as much as possible.

if you use **GET** method then your data will go as **params** i.e in URL

if you use **POST** method then your data will go in **req.body**

Edit your controller as

```
$scope.searchLocations = function () {
   var data = {};

    data.minDistance = $scope.minDistance;
    data.maxDistance = $scope.maxDistance;
    $http.post('/api/places',data})
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.searchLocations = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
}
```

and in your route replace you

```
app.get('/api/place') to app.post('/api/place')
```

then you will get **req.body.minDistance** & **req.body.maxDistance**

**if you want to use GET request** then your get method will be

```
$http({
    url: /api/places, 
    method: "GET",
    params: data
 });
```

and access from node as **req.params.minDistance** & **req.params.maxDistance**

Happy Coding!

Comment: So, using GET, they would be under req.params.minDistance?

Comment: yes check i have added GET request at last